# How set charset in a primefaces webapp?

Tags: java, jsf-2, character-encoding, primefaces

Let me share my unique disapointment with the primefaces 3.1, until now...
I'm using a phew components in a RichFaces app, everthing fine when i realized an issue, some characters in my native language are displayed wrong, even UTF-8 charset being declared in all places i know it's required.

The problem occur when is entered some special character like "São Paulo" in a  and submited the page. The data after submit is redisplays as "SÃÂ£o Paulo"

I already tried the folowing work-around:

1)Eclipse IDE : text file enconding option

2)jsf files:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

3)JBOSS server.xml:

```
<Connector protocol="HTTP/1.1" URIEncoding="UTF-8" port="${jboss.web.http.port}" address="0.0.0.0" 
         redirectPort="${jboss.web.https.port}" />
```

4)web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

5)jsf file:

```
<h:form acceptcharset="UTF-8" enctype="application/form-data">
```

6)upgrade the primefaces version to 3.2

Thanks for any help!
;-)

Comment: It's worth noting that PrimeFaces 3.2 has been released. I don't know if that fixes your problem, but I guess it can't hurt to try.

Comment: tried that right now, doesn't fix my issue...thanx anyway!

Comment: Are you using RichFaces or PrimeFaces? You yelled "RICHFACES" which is rather confusing. If RichFaces, are you using JSP or Facelets? Please describe the problem in more detail, it's not clear how and where exactly the problem is occurring. Describe the steps in detail how to reproduce the problem. Describe the expected/unexpected results in detail. E.g. "I entered XYZ in a `h:inputText`, after submit it redisplays as ZYX in `h:outputText`" and so on.

Comment: Yes i'm using both, facelets. ok i'll edit the post with more detail...

Comment: Thank you. What exactly does `Content-Type` response header contain? You can find it in Network tab of webbrowser's developer tool (press F12 in Chrome/IE9/Firebug). Is the form submit request been issued by ajax or a normal synchronous request? What if you try the other type of request?

Comment: `Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
X-Powered-By: Servlet/3.0; JBossAS-6, JSF/2.0
Pragma: No-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Expires: Wed, 31 Dec 1969 21:00:00 BRT
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Thu, 15 Mar 2012 13:17:39 GMT

200 OK`

I'm using a normal request, but i've tried with ajax and also occured  the issue. Let me tell more details, when i put a break-point at the ManageBean the field returns the right value, but when it will be send back to the view its encoding is corrupted.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

i've been forced to create a filter who sets the charset for every request...

```
public class CharacterEncodingFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
        FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

}
```

that's solve my issue

Answer (score 1):

I just uncomment that portion in conf/web.xml (Tomcat server web.xml) that filter all request and convert into UTF-8.

```
 <!-- A filter that sets character encoding that is used to decode URIs-->
 <!-- parameters in a POST request -->
 <filter>
        <filter-name>setCharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
 </filter>

  <!-- The mapping for the Set Character Encoding Filter -->
  <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>setCharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
```